# how to achieve 32rem margin with tailwind css class

Tags: css, tailwind-css

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin, max margin that can be given is 24 rem.

If I wish to have 32 rem margin how to achieve it ?

Comment: try using inline style, style="margin: 32rem !important";

Comment: Is this tailwind css or normal css ?

Comment: i am not familiar with tailwind css but my method will overwrite the margin property

Comment: Check https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing

Comment: @RickyStefano I feel it'll be risky to change 96 in tailwind css to let's say 525px as it will lead to more design confusions later and hard to debug problems. I felt they should be easier way to add new value as per user need, instead of overwriting existing values

Comment: uhm.... you can just extend the values? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing#extending-the-default-spacing-scale (same page as i linked before but with anchor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve it by extending the current configuration with something like this:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '128': '32rem', // following the standard of 128 / 4 = 32
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The great thing about this, is that it will keep all your already existing values!
More info available here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing#extending-the-default-spacing-scale

---

Otherwise, @wbsnail mention of JIT is a good idea, even if it should be used only in rares cases.

Comment: What does "JIT"  means ?

Comment: Just in Time mode as in here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Answer (score 1):

Try customize Tailwind's default spacing/sizing scale: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing

You can add larger size like:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    spacing: {
      '32': '32rem'
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can try tailwindCSS's JIT feature: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode, where you can achive this like:

```html
<div class="m-[32rem]"></div>
```